# Insert node at specified custom class iterator position

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, iterator, nodes

I'm trying to insert a node at a specified position, the issue is that the insertion happens one position after where I want it. For example:

insert 100 at `list.insert(list.begin()++, 100)`   in `1,2,3,4,5,6,7` results in:

`1,2,100,3,4,5,6,7`

I thought of decrementing the iterator, then inserting but that would be a workaround some flawed logic in my code but I cannot see where it is.

insert function

```cpp
iterator insert(iterator position, const T& value) {

        Node* newNode = new Node(value);

        if (position == List<T>::iterator(head_)) {
            newNode->next_ = head_;
            head_ = newNode;
        }
        else if (!position.iNode->next_) {
            position.iNode->next_ = newNode;
        }
        else {

            Node* tmp = new Node(value);
            tmp->next_= position.iNode->next_;
            position.iNode->next_ = tmp;
        }

        return position;
    }
```

iterator class

```cpp
class iterator
    {
    public:

        Node* iNode;
        iterator(Node* head): iNode(head){ }
        ~iterator() {}


        T& operator*() {
            return  iNode -> value_;
        }
    
        iterator& operator++() {
            iNode = iNode->next_;
            return *this;
        }

        iterator operator++(int ignored) {
            iNode = iNode->next_;
            return *this;
        }

        //! Is this iterator pointing at the same place as another one?
        bool operator== (const iterator& it) const {
            return this->iNode == it.iNode;
        }

        //! Is this iterator pointing at a different place from another?
        bool operator!= (const iterator& it) const {
            return this->iNode != it.iNode;
        }
    };
```

node class

```cpp
class Node {
    public:
        Node(T value) : value_(value) {}

        T value_;
        Node* next_;
        Node* prev_;

        Node* head_;
        Node* tail_;
    };
```

Comment: Compile your code and open your program in a debugger. Set a breakpoint at `iterator insert(iterator position, const T& value) {`, start your program and step line by line through the code. But you can see here `position.iNode->next_ = newNode;` and here `position.iNode->next_ = tmp;` that your code inserts the new elements after `position`.

Comment: I know this is the expected behaviour of my code I just cannot figure out how to fix it.

Comment: You fix it with pen and paper. You don't have the algorithm. You start with developing an algorithm for this problem. Draw list elements and connect them. Add a new list element and find out how to reconnect them. You are not at the point to work in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here in insert:

```
iterator insert(iterator position, const T& value) {

        Node* newNode = new Node(value);

        if (position == List<T>::iterator(head_)) {
            newNode->next_ = head_;
            head_ = newNode;
        }
        else if (!position.iNode->next_) {
            position.iNode->next_ = newNode;
        }
        else {
            Node* curr = head_; 
            while (curr->next_ != position.iNode) 
                {
                    curr = curr->next_;
                }

            newNode->next_ = curr->next_;
            curr->next_ = newNode;
        }

        return position;
    }
```

You insert a new node just after iterator position. But you need to insert it just before the new node.

By the way, I tested it in my own List class. If something go wrong just add a comment to my post.

Update: Actually, I fixed only part of the problem that time. Now the logic is:

1. Iterate from head to node before the iterator.
2. Connect new Node to the next of the node we iterated to in first step.
3. Connect node we iterated to in first step to new Node.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm trying it but it does not seem to work. It's still adding the element to one position after. I will try to debug more and figure out why.